# After Using Get Method , Clean query strings in Adress Bar,

Tags: php

My php code in one page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['gonder'])){....}

if(isset($_GET['ozelid'])){.....}


?>

<input type="submit" name="gonder"> 
<td> <a href=\"?ozelid=YERTUTUCU&fiyat=$haskur\" onclick=\"return confirm('Tahsil Edilsin?')\" >Tahsil</a>
```

First time after the page loads ,when I click submit, it is okay and it only runs   `if(isset($_POST['gonder'])){....}`

Again first time after the page loads , when I click the link then it only runs
`if(isset($_GET['ozelid'])){.....}`

However,  after the page loads, when click the link and then I click the submit button both `if(isset($_POST['gonder'])){....}` and `if(isset($_GET['ozelid'])){.....}` run, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one of these being called at a time, then I would suggest just using an ElseIf.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['gonder'])){....}

Elseif(isset($_GET['ozelid'])){.....}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check your form tag:

If you are using `<form action="#"` or keep the `action` attribute empty, the form is sent to the current page (in your case it's the page having the GET parameters).

Please check if you have the possibilty to set the `action` attribute of your form tag to something like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

You have to replace `index.php` with the name of your php file.

Answer (score 0):

After you processed the request you can send location header. Like so:

```
header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
die();
```

To your current url without get parameters. I guess this should be in your code in this block:

```
if(isset($_GET['ozelid'])){.....}
```